# ¿Cómo puedo unir a un solo array el siguiente array que contiene arrays dentro de ella?

Tags: php

Hola amigos buen día,

El array que tengo es el siguiente: `$array = [[1,9],[1,9]]` y lo que quiero es que a partir de ese array unir los valores a algo así `$array_unido = [1,9,1,9]`.

Comment: Hola! Has probado algo para intentar hacer eso? Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: tips: [usando array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php), tal vez [usando ...](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.variadics) tal vez también [usando array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-values) iterando o con recursión